# High Sierra reboot loop after data migration

Tags: macos, ssd, high-sierra, migration-assistant

I've installed a new SSD on my Mac Mini 2014. So I have a new SSD connected via PCIe and the old OEM HDD via SATA.

I've installed a fresh copy of High Sierra on the new SSD and seems to work well. But after using Migration Assistant (to copy data from HDD OS X installation to the new SSD) the system begins rebooting loop on Apple logo screen.

I've reinstalled it a few times, but the same thing happens after Migration Assistant. Any help?

Note: the OS on the old drive was the same (High Sierra).

Answer (score 1):

Try to install High Sierra again but change the format on you SSD drive to a HFS+ and run the Migration Assistant again.

I have the same issue when I boot. I think this is because we have a Mac from early 2015. I think the Mac will not boot a drive with APFS format yet. (Maybe a firmware update will fix this).

Answer (score 0):

I've skipped Computer, System & Printer (or something like this) checkbox and it went well.

Comment: It was fine as a comment two years ago, but promoting that to an answer leaves far too much open to interpretation & 'citation required'.